# How to fix "segmentation fault (core dumped)" error when accessing a string variable within a struct within a dynamic array

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, c++14

I am programming a simple game and I am keeping track of the users stats for each game they play in a session while the program is running. To do this, I made a struct called "game" which holds the statistics of the game played(game #, who won, who lost,# of turns, and if they chose to resign). I then made a dynamic array of these structs, which allocates one more section of memory for a new struct each time the number of games played goes up by one. Then all the statistics are outputted by running a for-loop which goes through and outputs the stats of each game played in that session. When outputting the int variable which holds the number of the game there is no problem, but once it reaches the string variable that holds the name of the winner I get a "segmentation fault (core dumped)" error.

I understand the error message means I am trying to access memory that I have no access too, so I made sure my dynamic array's capacity was larger than the index so I wasn't going outside of it's memory location, and even added extra capacity after each game but the error still persists.

I believe this part is whats causing the error when I try to access the "winner" string, just not sure why:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i <= index; i++){
         cout<<"Game "<<games[i].num<<"\t|\t"<<games[i].winner<<end;
    }
```

This is how I made my dynamic array:

```cpp
int index = 0;
int capacity = 1;
game *games;
games = (game *)malloc(sizeof(game)*capacity);
```

This is how I expand the array for a new game struct each time a new game is played.
Index goes up by one after each game, this code should make sure that capacity remains the same or larger than the index.

```cpp
if (index>=capacity) {
        capacity+=1;
        games = (game *) realloc(games, sizeof(game)*capacity);
}
```

This is the struct definition

```cpp
struct game
{
    int num;
    string winner;

};
```

Sorry in advance for any bad formatting, I am a noob at C++ and I am also new to this website. Be nice please :)

Comment: You can’t use `realloc` on non-trivial C++ types like `std::string`.  (That’s also not a good way of using it anyway—growing by only one and not checking for failure.)

Comment: `games = (game *) realloc(games, sizeof(game)*capacity);` -- Do not use `realloc`, and `malloc` in a C++ program like this.  Why are you not simply using `std::vector<game>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`std::realloc\` for non-POD types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905594/stdrealloc-for-non-pod-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
games = (game *)malloc(sizeof(game)*capacity);

games = (game *) realloc(games, sizeof(game)*capacity);
```

This `game` contains a C++ class called `std::string`. This is a class with a constructor and a destructor.

`malloc()` and `realloc` are C library functions, that know absolutely nothing, whatsoever, about any C++ class, or how to call its constructors or destructors.

You cannot use `malloc`, `realloc`, or `free` with C++ classes. Not `std::string`, or any other non-POD C++ class.

Fortunately, C++ has a very useful class called `std::vector` that will correctly manage a "dynamic array", correctly growing and shrinking, and allocating memory for its contents, and correctly constructing and destroying everything that needs to be constructed or destroyed.

Your code reinvents a wheel that has already been invented, called `std::vector`. It does everything the shown code manually does, with regards to size, capacity, etc... You're trying to duplicate `std::vector`'s logic, without any apparent benefit.

Completely get rid of all your code that uses `malloc`, `realloc`, and `free`, and replace it with `std::vector`. You will find more information on how to use `std::vector` in your C++ book.

Comment: Thank you so much, vectors would have been my first choice, but my professor wants us to grasp pointers and dynamic arrays better so he has prohibited them for this assignment. Fortunately I figured out I could just use a char to represent the winner instead of a string and now everything works fine. I guess I should've done some review on the rules of memory allocation before the semester started.

Comment: @slyce those functions  should not be used in C++ program outside rare case of new\delete operator re-definition. And pointers shouldn't be  vastly used in C++ outside of libraries, if not at all. Plus this doesn't explain concept of pointer in C++, it obfuscates it by C concept of pointer (the definitions are even different)

Comment: Because vectors are a natural use case here, if there was a specific reason you did not wish to use a vector, such as the one you described, then you should've explicitly called it out in your question. Really, this is not complicated: anyone with even a moderate knowledge of C++ will tell you here: "use a vector". So, don't you think you should've mentioned this up front, so that you don't end up with people telling you to do something you specifically need to avoid doing?

Comment: @slyce *but my professor wants us to grasp pointers and dynamic arrays better so he has prohibited them for this assignment.*  -- If that is the case, why did you choose to use `malloc` and `realloc` instead of `new[]`?  No C++ book that I know of shows usage of `malloc` or `realloc` in this manner -- if anything that book would show `new`.  In other words, you had to make a concerted effort to use these (wrong) functions, and not just naturally gravitate to what all C++ books show -- using `new[]`.  If you got this idea from your teacher, get a new teacher.